# sharepoint site user group setting

Tags: sharepoint-server

As shown in the figure,
[image: this is group setting page of the sharepoint user group]
Here, in this sharepoint site user group, group members are not able to add the new user to the group.
I have checked the radio button for **group members** for "**

who can edit the membership of the group?

**"
How to make the group members to enable to add new user to the group?
Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to Site Settings -> People and Groups (in Users and Permissions column).
Find your group and click it. Inside the group click New -> Add Users.
Thus you can edit group memberships.